# Is there any way to make IntelliJ IDEA file context menu searchable?

Tags: intellij-idea

I love IntelliJ IDEA, because it's conveniences of **keyboard input** and **quick search**, you can search almost everywhere, just input directly in the view and popups, like it's quick outline, search files, project struct and so on. It's fuzzy search is quick and powerful.

Context menu so powerful and frequently used, but there's no quick search. And I get used to keyboard input and **ideavim** plugin now, it's a good plugin. but the context menu makes me feeling so bad.

So, is there any way to do that? Making it searchable like quick fix, quick outline.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [related feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194472), feel free to vote.

Right now you can create your own [quick lists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-quick-lists.html) with the actions you need. Quick lists have the shortcuts by default.